# Adding points when plotting a graph: how to do with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

### My question

How can I add plots to the graph I am drawing, in order to have a more precise drawing?

---

### My code

I am learning how to plot graphs.

Here is the code I use. You can see on the picture that the curve is not smooth: one should use more plots to draw this graph.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-5:8]
\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-5.1,-1.6) grid (8.1,1.6);
\draw[->] (-5.2,0) -- (8.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.7) -- (0,1.7) node[right] {$\sin(x)$};
\draw[color=orange] plot function{sin(x)} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add `smooth` as the option.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-5:8]
\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-5.1,-1.6) grid (8.1,1.6);
\draw[->] (-5.2,0) -- (8.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.7) -- (0,1.7) node[right] {$\sin(x)$};
\draw[color=orange] plot[smooth] function{sin(x)} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With powerful `pgfplots`, there is a `samples` key using which you can add more data points to be plotted

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=-2,ymax=2,grid=major,
    ]    
    \addplot[domain=0:4*pi,samples=500]  {sin(deg(x))};   %% change samples value. you can also add smooth option
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With more `samples` plots become more smooth at the cost of compilation time. Some times it is advisable to use `gnuplot` from within `addplot` as gnuplot is better in doing computations.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=-2,ymax=2,grid=major,
    ]    
    \addplot[blue, samples=5000] gnuplot[domain = 0:4*pi] {sin(x)};   %% change samples value.
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`pgfplots` offers lot of goodies for plotting. I suggest you switch to it for plotting needs.

As suggested by Claudio Fiandrino, you can use the versatile `hobby` tikz library. There are two options - `quick hobby` and hobby` for open curves.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-5:8]
\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-5.1,-1.6) grid (8.1,1.6);
\draw[->] (-5.2,0) -- (8.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.7) -- (0,1.7) node[right] {$\sin(x)$};
\draw[color=orange] plot[quick hobby] function{sin(x)} ;    % quick hobby or simply hobby
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or even `hobby`...

Comment: Great.. looking for the complete answer, but don't expect another upvote from me: already done ;)

Comment: Yes, I had in mind `\draw[color=orange] plot[hobby] function{sin(x)} ;`..

Comment: Samples is TikZ option.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I think I am finished. Thanks for the hobby tip.

Comment: @HarishKumar: you're always welcome! I think having the hobby options for plots is a great feature.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino It is indeed a great feature. I never used it for plotting functions though.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I prefer how the tikz graphs look like, compared to to pgfplots + the pgfplot documentation frightened me!!! What does this hobby option?

Comment: @Colas `pgfplots` is not that difficult. `hobby` allows one to draw smooth curves and it uses Hobby's algorithm. For more details `texdoc hobby`.

Comment: @HarishKumar I would like to control the width of the graph. How can I do that?

Comment: @Colas If for `tikz` add `x=<dimension> to the option of `tikzpicture`. For example, `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm]` will reduce width by 50% (`x=2cm` will double the width). For `pgfplots` add `width=<dimension>` to the `axis` options → `\begin{axis}[width=2in,xmin=0,...]`

Answer (score 6):

You can change to [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,domain=-5:8, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$]
\addplot[orange,smooth] {sin(deg(x))} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]